# How to change column name if it contains certain characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to change the name of table columns using `SQL Server`.

The Database table looks like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Q115($) | Q215($) | Q315($) | .... | QXYY($)|

Where new columns are added over time in the format "Quarter"+"Year"+"($)"

**I want to write a query that does the following in Microsoft SQL Server:**

For all columns that contains "($)":

Change Name of Column from QXYY($) to 20YY QX

Comment: the answer for this depends on the db engine you're using which you haven't included in your question

Comment: I just have to say that's a pretty bad database design -- adding columns for each quarter of each year.  That's what rows are for.

Answer (score 0):

Changing column names is probably something you want to do manually instead of as a mass change. You can get a list of all the columns in all tables in your DB using the `sys.all_columns` table so something like

```
select      all_objects.name as Table_nm, all_columns.name as Column_nm
from        sys.all_columns
inner join  sys.all_objects
    on      all_objects.object_id = all_columns.object_id
where       all_columns.name like '%$%'
```

It looks like renaming columns is done through a Stored Procedure, so you could take the output of that query to create a string of other queries to update all the offending records.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188617.aspx

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Powershell:

```
push-location;
import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking;
pop-location;

$s = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server '.';
$tbl = $s.databases['MyDB'].tables['MyTbl'];
foreach ($col in $tbl.Columns) {
   if ($col -match '^Q([1-4])([0-9][0-9])\(\$\)$') {
      $newName = "20$($matches[2]) Q$($matches[1])";
      $col.Rename( $newName );
   }
}
```